# Angular 2 test doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have a problem starting tests. I'm using one of the angular 2 webpack starters and when I run `npm run test` I'm getting the next error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR: Unexpected token ')' at config/karma-test-shim.js:52056
```

The test looks like:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [AppComponent]});
  });
  it ('should work', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof AppComponent).toBe(true, 'should create AppComponent');
  });
});
```

What I have noticed is that when I use `()=>{}` code style this happens, but when I change it to ES5 code style `function(){}` it works.

Comment: Can you post your loader?

Comment: @DanielB What do you exactly mean by loader?

Answer (score 0):

Your `karma-test-shim.js` file gets loaded to the karma server *as is*, meaning it doesn't get transpiled. So when that file gets loaded into the PhantomJS headless browser and tries to run the script, it doesn't recognize the arrow function (`()=>{}`) because it's currently not supported.

If you change the testing browser to Chrome, it should work, as newer Chrome versions do support arrow functions. Or (as you've tried) just change all the arrow functions in that file to regular `function`s.

Comment: "If you change the testing browser to Chrome, it should work" <<< How can I achieve that?

Comment: The configured browser should be in the karm.conf file. Just Google how to  set it up.

Comment: Basically it involves installing the karma-<browser>-runner and configuring it in the karma.conf file

Comment: I have this line in karma.conf file - browsers: ['PhantomJS'] 

When I changed it to browsers: ['Chrome'] I'm getting the error:

06 12 2016 11:35:44.291:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "chrome": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

Do you know what plugin I need to install?

Comment: Ok so you should install `karma-chrome-launcher`. Then in the karma.conf in [the `plugins`](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/karma.conf.js#L15), add `require('karma-chrome-launcher')`

Comment: Thanks, now it starts but I'm getting the error:

Chrome 54.0.2840 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./app.component"
  at config/karma-test-shim.js:52053

If I remove import it works.